# Routing requests using cloudflare to different web applications

Tags: cloudflare, keystonejs, cloudflare-workers, terraform-provider-cloudflare

I currently have two web apps that are set up in cloudflare with the following CNAMEs. Both are keystonejs applications.

```
app1.example.com ===pointing to ===> AWS ALB 1
app2.example.com ===pointing to ===> AWS ALB 2
```

I have Cloudflare Enterprise set up, so i'm able to use the "Render Override" feature in my page rules. I have 2 page rules set up using the following:

```
www.example.com ===render override ===> app1.example.com
www.example.com/app2/* ===render override ===> app2.example.com
```

Now in order to access the keystonejs application on app2.example.com. The application is called using app2.example.com/pa

The problem that i'm facing is that render override doesnt allow me to use sub paths, and i do not want to use the forwarding rule. Do i need to make my keystone application accessible through the root url, namely app2.example.com/ ? or is there another way to do this? Otherwise, would i need to use a reverse proxy? such as nginx ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: Since you are an enterprise customer, I highly recommend contacting your Customer Success Manager and/or Solutions Engineer at Cloudflare. They are there to help with exactly these kinds of questions. That said, I'll answer the question here for the benefit of self-serve customers.*

I think when you say "Render Override" you actually mean "Resolve Override". This setting changes the DNS lookup for the request such that it is routed to a different origin IP address than it would be normally.

Note that Resolve Override does *not* rewrite the request in any way; it only routes it to a different server. So, a request to `www.example.com/app2/foo` will go to the server `app2.example.com`, but the path will still be `/app2/foo` (not `/foo`), and the `Host` header will still be `Host: www.example.com`.

It sounds like in your case you really want `/app2/*` to be rewritten to `/pa/*`, in addition to redirecting to a different origin. You can accomplish this using [Cloudflare Workers](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-workers/), which lets you execute arbitrary JavaScript on Cloudflare's edge. Here's what the script might look like:

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handle(event.request));
});

async function handle(request) {
  let url = new URL(request.url)  // parse the URL

  if (url.pathname.startsWith("/app2/")) {
    // Override the target hostname.
    url.host = "app2.example.com"

    // Replace /app2/ with /pb/ in the path.
    url.pathname = "/pb/" + url.pathname.slice("/app2/".length)

    // Send the request on to origin.
    return fetch(url, request)
  } else {
    // Just override the hostname.
    url.host = "app1.example.com"

    // Send the request on to origin.
    return fetch(url, request)
  }
}
```

With this deployed, you can remove your Resolve Override page rules, as they are now covered by the Worker script.

Note that the above script actually does rewrite the `Host` header in addition to the path. If you want the `Host` header to stay as `www.example.com`, then you will need to use [the `cf.resolveOverride` option](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/cloudflare-features/#resolve-override). This is only available to enterprise customers; ask your CSM or SE if you need help using it. But, for most cases, you actually want the `Host` header to be rewritten, so you probably don't need this.